# async await suitable to my case?

Tags: winforms, asynchronous, block, async-await

I've got a winform application, which has a database operation. Instead of the default UI blocking effect, I hope to display a special form like

`System is processing. please wait`

to tell users that the system is working. So basically I'm not looking for a real responsive UI. I still want to block the UI. I've achieved this goal with the backgroundworker component. Hookup the completed callback, then call the `RunWorkerAsync` in button click event handler, showdialog the processing form. Then in the completed callback, close the processing form.

I wonder if this scenario can be implemented with the new async/await mechanism. I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call blocking the UI is not blocking the UI. Blocking the UI thread means to stall message processing so that the UI cannot change and react to input. The window usually is ghosted by Windows if this is detected.

You want to show a modal dialog. You can do that with `BackgroundWorker` or in a more modern way with `async` and `await`. For example:

```
void MyClickHandler(...) {
 var form = new MyForm();
 Task myAsyncOperation = StartOperationAsync(form);
 form.ShowDialog();
 await myAsyncOperation;
}

async Task StartOperationAsync(Form formToClose) {
 await DoSomething();
 formToClose.Close();
}
```

All of this code is multiplexed on the UI thread. Thread-safety is not a concern.